# fadeIn works but fadeOut doesn't

Tags: jquery, html, css

I know this is supposed to be really simple, but I can't figure out what it is since I believe my code and syntax to be correct...basically I want my dropdown menu to fadeIn after hovering with mouse on top of the menu and the fadeOut when mouse leaves...thing that's bugging me is that the fadeIn is working, but the fadeOut is not

```
<ul class="menu">
    <a href="index.php"><li>HOME</li></a>
    <a href="about.php"><li>ABOUT US</li></a>
    <li class="work">
        OUR WORK
        <ul class="submenu">
            <a href="webdesign.php">
                <li>Webdesign</li>
            </a>
        </ul>
    </li>
    </a>
    <a href="clients.php"><li>CLIENTS</li></a>
    <a href="contact.php"><li>CONTACT</li></a>
</ul>
```

```js
$('.work').mouseover(function() {
    $('.submenu').fadeIn(400);
});

$('.work').mouseout(function() {
    $('.submenu').fadeOut(400);
});
```

Comment: syntax error, it should be rather obvious that there is a difference between the first event handler and the second one ?

Comment: Indeed...anchor tags cannot be children of `ul`..Wrap the `li` around the `a` not the other way round.

Comment: `mouseout()(` is the error they're referring to in case it isn't clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several syntax errors in your HTML and JS. Firstly, the `a` elements should be inside the `li`:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="index.php">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.php">ABOUT US</a></li>
    <li class="work">
        OUR WORK
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="webdesign.php">Webdesign</a></li>            
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="clients.php">CLIENTS</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.php">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then the `mouseout` declaration shouldn't have a separate set of brackets after it. In fact, you can shorten the logic by using `hover` instead:

```
$('.work').hover(function() {
    $('.submenu').fadeIn(400);
}, function() {
    $('.submenu').fadeOut(400);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pa8g41xe/)

Comment: Better answer as it also fixes the other errors within the code. +1

Comment: I've placed the `a` tags inside `li`  but trying to shorten the code like you suggested also made the "OUR WORK" fadeOut, when only the submenu should

Comment: Sounds like you're targeting the wrong element in the `.submenu` fadeOut selector

Answer (score 4):

You have invalid markup. ul element can only have li elements as their direct children. change the markup to:

```
<ul class="menu">
<li><a href="index.php">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="about.php">ABOUT US</a></li>
<li class="work">
    OUR WORK
    <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="webdesign.php">
            Webdesign
        </a></li>
    </ul>
</li>

<li><a href="clients.php">CLIENTS</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.php">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
```

For event binding,you have syntax error for mouseout event. you can also use `.hover()` instead of mouseover and mouseleave event.

```
$('.work').hover(function(){
    $('.submenu').fadeIn(400);
},function(){
    $('.submenu').fadeOut(400);
})
```